# How should i include my own small "webpages"?

Tags: java, android

I wish to have small simple HTML-webpages in my app. What approach should i take? Should i write it in HTML and keep it under my resources or should i create a webpage and collect the articles from there?

I will need about 30-50 small pages with simple text and images.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the options you can go with.

1) Putting HTML files in assets (Directly impacts on apk size)

2) Loading your pages 
   - Configure server
   - Design Webpage (HTML you done already!) 
   - Load WebView

Both have own perks and falls but a not big one to worry.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your HTML files in the `assets` folder (create it if you dont have one) and then use this code to display them.

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
 wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

[image]